# How do I disable a particular cipher suite in openssl?

Tags: openssl

I want to secure my server from FREAK attack so I want to disable all the cipher suites that uses export grade RSA key from Openssl. Is there a way to disable a particular cipher suite in openssl? If yes, how do i do it?

Comment: it's also appreciate to know how to disable a/multiple particular cipher suite at compile time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there a way to disable a particular cipher suite in openssl? If yes, how do i do it?

To answer the direct question of disabling a particular cipher suite, do so by removing it from the cipher suite list passed to `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` or `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list`:

```
int rc = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ALL:!NULL-MD5:!NULL-SHA");
assert(0 != rc);
```

You can do it on a `SSL*` with:

```
int rc = SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, "ALL:!NULL-MD5:!NULL-SHA");
assert(0 != rc);
```

In the above, `NULL-MD5` is `SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5` and `NULL-SHA` is `SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA`. You can get the list of mappings from the [`openssl ciphers`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ciphers) command.

---

You can also disable export ciphers with `!EXP`:

```
int rc = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ALL:!EXP");
assert(0 != rc);
```

And you can do it on a `SSL*` with:

```
int rc = SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, "ALL:!EXP");
assert(0 != rc);
```

---

You can see what `"ALL:!EXP"` equates to with the OpenSSL command (note the single quote so the shell does not get a hold of the bang):

```
$ openssl ciphers 'ALL:!EXP'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA:
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA:DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384...
```

You can count the number of cipher suites with:

```
$ openssl ciphers 'ALL:!EXP' | tr ':' ' ' | wc -w
     124
```

That tells you your `ClientHello` will use at least 248 bytes due to the 124 cipher suites. Ideally, you should advertise the 16 or so suites you *really* want.

---

You usually configure your cipher suites using `"HIGH"` only. It excludes `"MEDIUM"`, `"LOW"` and `"EXP"`. Here's how my call sometimes look:

```
int rc = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "HIGH:!ADH:!MD5:!RC4:!SRP:!PSK:!DSS");
assert(0 != rc);
```

Be sure to exclude the anonymous gear (`!ADH`) because its included by default. `!MD5` and `!RC4` are used because they are weak/wounded. `!SRP`, `!PSK`, and `!DSS` are used to trim the list of ciphers further because they are not usually used.

You can also do the same with a `SSL*` and `SSL_set_cipher_list`.

If you call `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` and `SSL_set_cipher_list` on a server, the the cipher suite list will be trimmed further depending on the type of key in the certificate.

---

In the previous block, I said *... how my call sometimes look*. Usually, I like to specify the 16 or so I want to use with:

```
string GetCipherSuites()
{
    static string ciphers = ""

#if defined(ALLOW_ECDSA)
    "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
    "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"
#endif

    "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"

#if defined(ALLOW_DSA)
    "DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
#endif

    "DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"

#if defined(ALLOW_DSA)
    "DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"
#endif

    "DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"

#if defined(ALLOW_DSA)
    "DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:"
#endif

    "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:"

#if defined(ALLOW_DSA)
    "DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:"
#endif

    "DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:"

#if defined(ALLOW_DSA)
    "EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:"
#endif

    "EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:"

#if defined(ALLOW_DSA)
    "DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:"
#endif

    "DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:";

    return ciphers;
}
```

Comment: Means, where is the "cipher suite list" located?

Comment: where should these changes happen ?