# Is the order of cipher names in TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.SSLOptions.CipherList important?

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, indy

I'm limiting the ciphers that my webservice allows to only these TLS 1.x ciphers:

<s>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256

    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

    TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA

    TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA

    TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA

    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA</s>

**Update** in response to [Dave Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085)'s comment:

I now take the ciphers generated from [this SO answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/77018/13695), in that order.
Because we currently use Delphi XE2/Indy 10.5.8.0/OpenSSL 1.0.2f I leave out the ECDHE ciphers, these are [too cumbersome to implement with these software versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36146053/512728).
Also, we still allow TLS 1.0.
After the update to Delphi Seattle 10 we'll disallow TLS 1.0 and put the ECDHE ciphers back in.

This leaves:

```
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcc15)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x67)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256 (0xc4)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x88)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x45)
```

Converted to OpenSSL names (according to [Mapping OpenSSL cipher suite names to RFC names](https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mappping.html)) these are:

```
DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 
- cannot find the equivalent for 0xc4 - anyone? -
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA 
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA 
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256
```

The order in which a server offers ciphers is important, but do I have control over this order? The CipherList is a string property containing these names concatenated with '+':

```
TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.SSLOptions.CipherList := 'DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SH:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256';
```

If so, what is the recommended order?

Note that, since my webservice is the server, I have set `SSLOptions.Mode := sslmServer`.

<s>* These are the ones that the [nmap](http://nmap.org/) script [ssl-enum-ciphers](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html) grades with an 'A'</s>

Comment: I don't know how that nmap script is grading, but A for **RC4 is very wrong**; it's so badly weakened by numerous attacks it was recently officially prohibited for TLS, see Wikipedia for details and links. And if 'DHE-RSA ... (dh 256)' means a DHE group of 256 bits, that's *grossly* insecure -- it's about like Logjam cubed! If you want security try http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51680/optimal-web-server-ssl-cipher-suite-configuration and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76993/now-that-it-is-2015-what-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-should-be-used-

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks, updated the list.

Comment: Re update: also verify DHparams size if you haven't. I don't know if your openssl build is patched, but upstream 1.0.2 doesn't support CHACHA nor any CAMELLIA with SHA2; the website indicates 1.1.0 (now in beta) will have (apparently all) CHACHA, and CAMELLIA-SHA2 only with ECDHE (not DHE, or for that matter plainRSA). Note that OpenSSL silently ignores unrecognized items in a cipherstring as long as at least one item is valid and produces a nonempty list.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for that additional remark, but I now get into unfamiliar territory. I know *some* things about ciphers, but having to deal with this level of detail as an 'ordinary' programmer is getting a bit much ;-) Do you have recommendations on things I can read to really understand all this?

Comment: see not-really-answer (unless it gets voted down or 'hammered')

Answer (score 5):

> Is the order of cipher names in `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.SSLOptions.CipherList` important?

Mostly Yes.

TLS does *not* specify who decides on the cipher. Conventionally, the server honors the client's preference. That is, the server will use the client's first preference if its available and enabled, or the client's second preference if its available and enabled, and so on.

Most libraries allow a server to override the behavior. For example, with OpenSSL, `SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE` option. In this case, the server will match the server's first preference if the client advertises it, the server's second preference if the client advertises it, and so on.

For servers I control, I tune the cipher suite list and usually set `SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE` because many clients don't pay attention to the details. They just throw the soup of cipher suites in the ClientHello hoping something sticks.

---

> The order in which a server offers ciphers is important, but do I have control over this order?

Yes.

At the server, determine your order of cipher suites, and then set them with `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` or `SSL_set_cipher_list`. By setting the list, you ensure `RC4-MD5` is not used even its the client's first choice (presuming you omit it). For maximum impact, also set `SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE` context option.

Also see [How do I disable a particular cipher suite in openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29178652/608639) The context is OpenSSL, but it should give you an idea of where to go in Delphi.

---

> (Comments): What's not clear to me from your answer: Does the CipherList property already signify an order? If I look at the underlying Delphi/Indy code I see that it is just a wrapper for external function `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list : function(_para1: PSSL_CTX; const str: PAnsiChar): TIdC_INT cdecl = nil; in IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas`

If I am understanding Delphi properly, then I believe the answer is Yes, it does. But its probably using either (1) OpenSSL's default list, or (2) a Delphi default list. Both are probably something like *`"ALL:!EXP:!LOW"`* or similar. In either case, you will want to tune it to suite your taste.

If you are interested in what the list looks like when its put on the wire, use Wireshark to inspect the *ClientHello*. Its easy to generate one with `s_client`, and it shows you what OpenSSL's default cipher suite list looks like:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.ietf.org:443 -tls1 -servername www.ietf.org
```

And the corresponding Wireshark trace with 55 default cipher suites stuffed into it:

[image]

You can also improve your security posture and reduce the number of cipher suites with the `-cipher` option and *`"HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4"`*. The cipher suite count will be reduced to about 35.

```
 $ openssl s_client -connect www.ietf.org:443 -tls1 -servername www.ietf.org \
     -cipher 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4'
```

If you don't like TripleDES and Cameilla, then you can reduce it to about 20 cipher suites with:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.ietf.org:443 -tls1 -servername www.ietf.org \
    -cipher 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES:!CAMELLIA'
```

---

Now, suppose a client is configured with only `RC4-MD5` and a server is configured with only `AES-GCM`. I.e., there's no intersection of cipher suites between client and server. In this case, you will get an error in OpenSSL. The error will be 0x1408A0C1, "no shared cipher suites". It will look something like this at the server:

```
140339533272744:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1353
```

---

For OpenSSL-based clients and server, you can determine the default cipher suite list with the *"DEFAULT"* string. That's literally what its called (check the [`ciphers(1)` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html)).

There's 103 of them, which includes weak and wounded algorithms. In practice, you want to pair it down to 16 or so cipher suites you feel comfortable using (i.e., your security posture):

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'DEFAULT' | cut -f 1 -d " " | wc -l
     103
```

And:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'DEFAULT' | cut -f 1 -d " "
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA
DH-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
DH-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
AES256-GCM-SHA384
AES256-SHA256
AES256-SHA
CAMELLIA256-SHA
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA
SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA
SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA
DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA
DH-RSA-SEED-SHA
DH-DSS-SEED-SHA
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA
DH-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
DH-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
AES128-GCM-SHA256
AES128-SHA256
AES128-SHA
SEED-SHA
CAMELLIA128-SHA
IDEA-CBC-SHA
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
RC4-SHA
RC4-MD5
PSK-RC4-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA
DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA
ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
DES-CBC3-SHA
PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
DH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
DH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
DES-CBC-SHA
```

Answer (score 2):

Meta: not an answer to the question but response to comment. To 'really understand' SSL/TLS isn't really programming and is a big question that may be 'too broad' for SO. But some thoughts anyway:

- The **definitive guide** to SSL/TLS as a standardized protocol, or really family of them, is of course the RFCs that define them, plus where applicable the external standards referenced by those RFCs (like FIPS 197 for AES, PKCS#1 for RSA, SECG1 for ECC, etc). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) has a good overview and (AFAICT) complete list of references.
- If you just want a general understanding of what the pieces are and how they work (like RSA vs DHE vs ECDHE, and AES vs TDES or HMAC vs AEAD) Wikipedia is also good, and so is the **canonical Q&As on security.SE**
- A middle gound might be **Ivan Ristic's new 'Bulletproof' book**; he's the guy behind the widely-used and well-regarded SSLLabs test and the book is linked [from that homepage](https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html). I haven't read the actual book, but a few years ago he showed and discussed on his blog some of the material planned to go in the book and I thought that looked excellent.

Also, you are not implementing the standard directly; you are using an implementation that is a version of OpenSSL, and in today's software ecosystem **OpenSSL can vary**. First OpenSSL itself has a number of build (aka compile-time) options. And I know of Delphi only in outline and I don't know if the OpenSSL version you identify is provided with or for Delphi (or Indy?) or 'pulled in' from the OS or elsewhere, and in any case who built it with what options and possibly even modifications (patches). (For comparison, I commonly use RedHat-based and Debian-based Linuxes that backport patches so that a package identified as for example '1.0.1e' is usually different, sometimes significantly so, from other versions that are also identified as '1.0.1e'.)